# ImageField django. How to use?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

How upload images? How I can get images on post request?
I have model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(uploat_to=file_path)
```

Serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('image')
```

Viewset:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = []
    model = MyModel
```

JSON:

```
{
    "image" : what I should keep here
}
```

Or i can't send image in json?

Comment: Do you want to do uploads in a regular fashion (upload to a temp file and then rename it and save as ImageFile) or actually send image content as POST data (will only work for relatively small images)

Comment: I want send image content in POST data. I just want test upload method, but i don't know how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I decide convert image to base64 string and send in POST data. On server Side I create new serializer which convert base64string to file.